# Network flow database in Power Query table

Tags: database, excel, powerquery

I have the following Excel table:

[image: Sample Table in Excel]

Columns A, B and D are given (data). Other columns are calculated. The formula in each of the columns is given below.

[image: Formula in each column of Excel Table]

Given Columns A,B and D, can create this table be created with Power Query?

Comment: This looks like a circular definition to me. Column F is defined in terms of Column C which references Column F.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with 1 of the looping mechanisms: List.Generate, List.Accumulate or recursive function.

As the number of iterations is known, I prefer List.Accumulate.

In the query below, List.Accumulate builds a list of records with the fields that must be added to Source.

The resulting table is constructed via lists of column values and a new table type.

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    IncomingSupplies = List.Buffer(Source[Incoming Supply]),
    GenerateFlow = 
        List.Accumulate(
            List.Skip(IncomingSupplies),
            {[Beginning On Hand Inventory = Source[Starting Inventory]{0},
              Shipments = 0.5 * #"Beginning On Hand Inventory",
              Ending On Hand = #"Beginning On Hand Inventory" + IncomingSupplies{0} - Shipments]},
            (Result,Supply) =>
                Result &
                {[Beginning On Hand Inventory = List.Last(Result)[Ending On Hand],
                  Shipments = 0.5 * #"Beginning On Hand Inventory",
                  Ending On Hand = #"Beginning On Hand Inventory" + Supply - Shipments]}),
    NewTableType = Value.Type(Table.AddColumn(Source,"Records",each [], type[])),
    CombineSourceAndFlow = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source)&{GenerateFlow},NewTableType),
    ExpandFlow = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(CombineSourceAndFlow, "Records", {"Beginning On Hand Inventory", "Shipments", "Ending On Hand"}),
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ExpandFlow,{{"Beginning On Hand Inventory", Int64.Type}, {"Shipments", Int64.Type}, {"Ending On Hand", Int64.Type}}),
    Reordered = Table.ReorderColumns(Typed,{"Month", "Starting Inventory", "Beginning On Hand Inventory", "Incoming Supply", "Shipments", "Ending On Hand"})
in
    Reordered
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works great! Need to see if this scales.